# UITableViewController doesn't seem to refresh when reloadData goes from non-zero to zero sections on iPad

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

On iPad, in a UISplitViewController, I have a UITableViewController in the right section showing the details of what is selected on the left. So when I deselect everything on the left, consequently setting the detail object to nil in the detail view, I would like the table to clear and to display a message to invite the user to select an element.

That's why I have the following in my detail UITableViewController subclass:

```
var reference: Reference? {
    didSet {
        self.refreshInterface()
    }
}

func refreshInterface() {
    if let titleLabel = self.titleLabel {
        if let ref = reference {
            titleLabel.text = ref.projectName
        } else {
            titleLabel.text = NSLocalizedString("Please select a reference", comment: "")
        }
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if(self.reference != nil) {
        return 5
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}
```

And I checked with the debugger that after I set the reference to nil, numberOfSections is called and returns 0. But then for some reason, all the UI of the table isn't cleared. I still have the same rows and sections as when I had a reference selected. Am I missing something? Is this a potential bug in Cocoa Touch?

Comment: You're not doing the above on a background thread, are you?   Might be worth checking.

Comment: I really don't know, but when I see "potential bug in Cocoa Touch" I tend to first blame something else - like me! (Seriously, I'm not that great a programmer - even after 40 years.) That said, do you have something both *complete* and *duplicatable* that I can try? I'm pretty good with `UITableViews`, have both iPads and iPhones, and maybe could help. As it is? You haven't given me enough for that.

Comment: @dfd you are so totally right. I'm also very suspicious when somebody tells me they think they found a bug in such a mature framework. But then again, I've been using table views for a very long time and I thought I tried everything. Even here I was hopeful that it was a background thread issue, but I'm using Firebase to query my data and normally Firebase callbacks run on the main thread. Just to be sure, I wrapped my refreshInterface() call in a DispatchQueue.main.async{} but it didn't change a thing.

Comment: Now you've mentioned something I've never used - Firebase. Do you think that's the culprit? If so, maybe tag it as such?

Comment: I figured it out. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was not in my detail view controller, but in the master one. I didn't take into account that when I show a detail view controller when selecting an item in the main one, the split view controller creates another instance of the detail view controller each time. And since I was setting the detail object on the old instance, the old instance was updated but another one was already displayed. All I had to do to fix my issue was to make sure that I always set my detail object on the current instance of the detail view controller.

I hope this is useful to somebody.